# Reusing code in switch statement (Java)

Tags: java, switch-statement

I would like to use a `switch` statement, but I am not able to construct it without either duplicating code or using an accompanying `if` statement.  Is there a way around this?

I have 5 cases, and for all but one of them I would like to perform a certain action.  So with a `switch` statement, I can just do:

```
switch(x) {
case A:
    foo();
    break;
case B:
case C:
case D:
case E:
    bar();
    break;
}
```

Easy.  But the difficulty comes in that I also need to perform another distinct action for each one, so I can't use the fall-through feature of the cases.  So I'm reduced to either

```
switch(x) {
case A:
    foo();
    baz(0);
    break;
case B:
    bar();
    baz(1);
    break;
case C:
    bar();
    baz(2);
    break;
case D:
    bar();
    baz(3);
    break;
case E:
    bar();
    baz(4);
    break;
}
```

which smells to me because of having to repeat `bar()` every time, or

```
switch(x) {
case A:
    baz(0);
    break;
case B:
    baz(1);
    break;
case C:
    baz(2);
    break;
case D:
    baz(3);
    break;
case E:
    baz(4);
    break;
}
if (x != A) { bar(); }
```

which doesn't duplicate any code, but it bothers me that there I need to use both `switch` and `if`.

I guess one other alternative would be to use a map, like

```
Map<X, Integer> m = new HashMap<X, Integer>();
m.put(A, 0);
m.put(B, 1);
m.put(C, 2);
m.put(D, 3);
m.put(E, 4);

if (m.get(x) == 0) {
    foo();
} else {
    bar();
}
baz(m.get(x));
```

but now I've introduced a whole data structure just to clean this up. (And when you count the initialization of the map, it's not even that much cleaner.)

Any tips?

Comment: And you cannot/do not want to add `if(arg == 0) bar();` to `baz`?

Comment: I suppose I could, but I wanted it to be more general... in fact, in the code I have, it's not even `bar()`, it's just an assignment statement.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Is `x` by any chance an enum?  In which case just move the method to the enum instead of switching.

```
enum Employee {
    SENIOR {
        @Override
        public int salary() {
            return 60;
        }
    },
    JUNIOR {
         @Override
         public int salary() {
            return 40;
         }
    };

    public abstract int salary ();
}
```

And calling

```
  employee.salary();
```

Is much better than switching.

Yes; you will have to duplicate method calls, but I think this is correct and clear.  Or...  use a constructor in your enum. Excuse contrived mix of "Employee" code with "foobar" code.

```
   private final boolean flag;
   Employee(int flag) {
       this.flag = flag;
   }

   public int method() {
       if(flag) {
            secondMethod();
       }
       alwaysMethod();
   }
```

Comment: Yes, `x` is an enum. I think you are on to something.

Comment: I like this solution the best, using a constructor in the enum rather than duplicating the method definitions. Thanks.

Comment: IMHO, using using A,B,C... and foo, bar, ... would actually make it more understandable w.r.t. the OPs question.

Comment: Yeah, nice solution, but imo using enum constructor with parameter is better.

Comment: Didn't know about methods in enums, here's a good read: http://www.ajaxonomy.com/2007/java/making-the-most-of-java-50-enum-tricks

Answer (score 1):

I would split logic by pass `x` to `baz` and create new switch there:

```
switch(x) {
case A:
    foo();
    break;
case B:
case C:
case D:
case E:
    bar();
    baz(x); // < --- 
    break;
}


void baz(SomeEnum val){
 switch(val) {/* ...*/}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I guess your cases are fixed so you can use enum and just exclude one of them.

```
public enum MyCase {
   A, B, C, D, E;
}
```

and the condition

```
MyCase x;
...
if MyCase.A.equals(x) {
    foo();
} else {
    bar();
}
baz(x);
// or if the oridnal value is required
baz(x.ordinal);
```